# dart newbie progress debugging error here

Tags: dart

```
  main(){
  dynamic input = "saya sedang belajar menjadi programmer yang handal";
  List<String> huruf = input.split('');
  print('input : $input');
  var vokal = ['a','i','e','o','u'];
  var outputk = '';
  var outputv = '';
  int index = 0;

  do{
    if (vokal.contains(huruf[index])) {
      outputk += ' ';
      outputv += huruf[index];
    }else{
      outputk += huruf[index];
      outputv += ' ';
    }
  }while(index<huruf.length);

  print('output konsonan : $outputk');
  print('output vokal = $outputv');
}
```

why the outputk and outputv result wont come out? when i debug it just print the input
i have been told that i need to change the index but i dont know to change to what

sry for bad english btw

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just forgot to increment `index` in your loop. So it create an infinite loop. Adding a `++` to the while condition makes it work.

```
} while (++index<huruf.length);
```

Comment: thank you for your help, when i start debugging per lines it go the way i want it. but when i straight debug them all it just show nothing. how can that happen.